# Catalyst: How do I make DBIx::Class::Schema::Loader::make_schema_at() static preserve case?

Tags: perl, schema, case, catalyst, dbix-class

I'd like to be able to force the 
**PACKAGE**->add_columns() to not lc everything.  I know there's a `preserve_case` option, but I can't figure out where to put it. Is there a 'myproj_schema.pl' file I can create in /conf ?

Answer (score 2):

```
make_schema_at(
    'My::Schema',
    {   dump_directory  => "$FindBin::Bin/../lib/",
        use_namespaces  => 1,
        preserve_case   => 1,
        },
    $connect_info
    );
```